# How can I make the list ordered alphabetically based on the rental properties names?

Tags: html, css, list

I am trying to make the list that displays the rows of data to organize alphabetically based on the rental property's name. Right now they are all out of order and I am not sure if this is accomplished through CSS or HTML. The webpage I am speaking of can be found at http://clearwaterfloridabeachrentals2.imbookingsecure.com/rentals/allrentals/

Comment: I don't think this can be achieved using CSS (or indeed HTML - unless you manually order the list items yourself). You may have to use Javascript. I'm not 100% sure however, so wait for more responses.

Comment: how is this list generated? Is it hard-coded in HTML or do you receive it from a database? If you get it from a database it would be very ease to sort the result alphabetically by the rental property's name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see that your data is coming through a web service (through Ajax), In this case the web service must send the sorted data to UI. Because even if you achieve sorting of the loaded data (using javaScript that is) your sorting will remain incorrect as the users are able to choose 'load more results' and the new data which will come will again not be sorted.

As a general rule whenever there is a web service to load paginated data (like multiple pages OR scroll to load), it is best if the service itself handles the pagination and the sorting.